# java files containing unicode don't compile

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding, utf-8, javac

I downloaded an open-source project called PdfClown. Running it's samples it seems to run just fine.

But, when I try to change any java file which contains unicode bytes, it doesn't compile showing me compilation error as followed:

> [javac] C:\PDFClown\java\pdfclown.samples.cli\src\org\pdfclown\samples\cli\UnicodeSample.java:75: error: **unmappable character for encoding Cp1252**

I've changed the file, and also it's container to UTF-8, but it didn't help.

Does anyone have a clue?

Thanks!

Just to mention, this project works with ant, which means the compilation process isn't run directly by the user, but rather using a build.xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell the compiler which encoding is used in the source files.

```
javac -encoding encoding
```

[javac parameter documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This project works with Ant in eclipse, do you know how I change the encoding there? (I don't run it myself on the command line)

Answer (score 3):

You need the `encoding` attribute on your `<javac>` task:

```
<javac srcdir="src" destdir="classes"
       source="1.6" target="1.6"
       classpathref="compile.class.path"
       encoding="UTF-8" />
```